# awk subtract different columns

Tags: linux, awk

I want to group duplicate rows and subtract the values in the cols from these rows. Any idea how I can do this ?

Example:

```
dbstat 100 90 80 60 1000 
dbstat 10 10 10 20 
test 5 5
output should be: 
dbstat 90 80 70 40 1000 
test 5 5
```

update:
For other files I have to sum the values for matching rows and this works fine using:

awk '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {a[$1][i]+=$i}} END{ for (j in a) {s=j; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {s=s" "a[j][i]}; print s}}' 
But changing += to -= doesn't subtract, it still does a sum of the values but puts a minus sign before.

Thank you.

Comment: You have to show us the sample of expected output as well as your efforts too in code tags kindly do so and let us know then.

Comment: Please edit your Q to show your best attempt to solve the problem. Also please clarify : is the rule to "always subtract any `dbstat` record value from the first instance of of that record"? What if /Can there be 2ndary records with neg values, i.e. `-10 -10 10 20` and if so, what should be the result? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
test1 100 20 25 30
test1 10 10
test1 30 0 2
test2 500
test2 100 50 90
test2 10 0
test3 100 100 100
$
$ cat tst.awk
p != $1 {
    for (i in c)
        p = p OFS c[i]
    if (p)
        print p
    p = $1
    delete c
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i)
        c[i] = $i
    next
}
{
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i)
        c[i] -= $i
}
END {
    for (i in c)
        p = p OFS c[i]
    print p
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
test1 60 10 23 30
test2 390 -50 -90
test3 100 100 100
```

---

If duplicate columns are not grouped:

```
$ cat file2
test2 500
test1 100 20 25 30
test2 100 50 90
test1 30 0 2
test2 10 0
test3 100 100 100
test1 10 10
$
$ cat tst2.awk
{
    f = ($1 in a)
    for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i)
        a[$1][i] -= (f ? $i : -$i)
}
END {
    for (k in a) {
        o = k
        for (i in a[k])
            o = o OFS a[k][i]
        print o
    }
}
$
$ awk -f tst2.awk file2
test1 60 10 23 30
test2 390 -50 -90
test3 100 100 100
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't have to be awk, this perl script gives your desired output for your sample input:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use List::MoreUtils qw/pairwise/; # Non-core; install through your OS or CPAN.

my %records;

while (<>) {
  my ($key, @cols) = split /\s+/;
  $records{$key} =
    [ pairwise { defined $a ? $a - ($b // 0) : $b } @{$records{$key}}, @cols ];
}

foreach my $key (sort keys %records) {
  say "$key @{$records{$key}}";
}
```

It produces output in sorted order, like your example. If rows are supposed to be in the order they first appear in your real input, that's doable too. It wasn't clear from your sample since that starts out sorted.

It also doesn't require duplicates to be consecutive - is that important?